# How to mock out some functions inside a module which I want to be imported?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

> **CAUTION: This situation was happened because of a mistake. Check my answer.**

I have a python file (myfile.py) which I want to test its content with Pytest. (The content is changing dynamically)
I've wrote this code:

```py
import importlib

def test_myfile(capsys, monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr('builtins.input', lambda s: "some_input")

    # Create a module from the custom Problem file and import it
    my_module = importlib.import_module("myfile")

    # Rest of the test script
```

when I run the test I'm getting this error:

```
OSError: reading from stdin while output is captured
```

The error has been produced because there is an `input()` instruction in myfile.py and it means that mocking that function was futile.

**My Question:**
How can I mock out some functions inside a module I want to import?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? When copying your code as-is and generating a sample file, say `echo "input('foo')" > myfile.py` or `echo -e "def spam():\n    return input('foo')\n\nspam()" > myfile.py`, I don't get the error as monkeypatching does its job. Running Python 3.6.10, pytest 5.4.1.

Comment: I'm not near my laptop now, assume that myfile.py has just a line that asks a parameter from the user. e.g. `x = input('enter x: ')` if it works for you, let me check my python and pytest version and create a sample to reproduce the error @hoefling

Comment: No, no luck reproducing with it either (although the code is not different from the samples I tried).

Comment: success reproduce error when `monkeypatch.setattr('builtins.input', lambda s: "some_input")` commented out, but i don't think it is the reason. so please provide python version, pytest version and complete minimal code.

Comment: forgive me... I found the root of my issue. It's occurred because of that `myfile` was running when pytest was collecting test methods. so this question is wrong and should be deleted I think. @hoefling and @elprup

Comment: @mahyard What do you mean by "it was running"?

Comment: @a_guest I was using `py.test test_runner.py test_case.py` to test user input which was saved in test_case.py. I was getting the second parameter inside my test method. But before running my test method pytest imported both files to find test methods. It was failing to import test_case.py

Comment: To fix the problem I've added a parameter to py.test and now I'm running test process like this `py.test test_runner.py --program test_case.py`

Comment: @mahyard Would you like to add that as an answer? It would also be helpful to update the question to provide more details about what exactly caused the problem.

Comment: @a_guest I did so. It would be very nice if you check and correct my writing mistakes. thank you

Comment: @hoefling your comment was the main thing that helped me to find my mistake. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that I was looking wrong place to find a solution.
actually I use pytest to check a learner response and grade it. this was the way I did that at the moment I asked this question.

```
py.test test_runner.py test_case.py -v
```

This will test the user response which is saved in test_case.py ( I get the second parameter inside my test method and load its content and for example run a desired  function ). Then I was examining the report of pytest to see if there was an error or failure to decide about the result. (pass/failure)
normally pytest was failing if there was an error in users code (e.g. syntax error) or if the test was failing (e.g. didn't return what it must return)

This time there was an error I didn't want to stop the test. I want to mock out `input()` function in users code. when I was running the command, before running my test method, pytest imported both files to collect test methods. It was failing to import test_case.py because of the `input()` function. It was not even reach the line I asked to mock that function and failed in the init stage.

At last to fix the problem I've added a parameter to py.test and now I'm running test process like this:

```
py.test test_runner.py --program test_case.py -v
```

In this form pytest doesn't look in `test_case.py` for test methods and doesn't fail.

hope this experience helps someone else